# UIScrollView with multiple UITableViews? How best to set this up?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, interface-builder

[image: Custom AccountViewController NIB]

So the above is a screenshot from IB of my custom UIViewController. This main view contains lots of information. The ImageViews are temporary placeholders just for information / buttons to help me get an idea for my layout.

You'll see at the bottom I have dumped a UIScrollView. What I want to do is dump 3 UIView's inside the ScrollView, where each UIView contains a UITableView. This NIB/XIB file though is getting very cluttered and messy. I would like to create a new NIB which loads inside the UIScrollView. What's the best way to go about doing this?

Do I dump a new UIViewController into this XIB file, and then make the delegate of ScrollView the new ViewController ? then I can just set a custom nib for that UIViewController? Is that the proper way to do this?

Still coming to grips with Interface Builder and more advanced app. development!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with Scroll Views and the content inside of them, this is what I usually do...

I put the scroll view in my main view and create an IBOutlet in my view controller that is connected to it.

Then I create a second UIView in the xib that is my Content View (contentsOfScrollView) and create an IBOutlet in my view controller that is connected to it.

Then in my viewDidLoad I programmatically put the content view into the scroll view, like so:

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.contentsOfScrollView];
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.contentsOfScrollView.frame.size;
```

[image]